# Handling Many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

Here what table im working on:
`restaurant` (restaurant information)
`restaurant_hours` (restaurant operational hours)
`restaurant_tags`  (tag about restaurant)

1 restaurant can have more than 1 restaurant_hours and more than 1 restaurant_tags

**Result of querying multiple table:**

```
+----+---------------+-------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+
| id | name          | state | cuisine | day     | open_time | close_time | tag   |
+----+---------------+-------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+
| 44 | Restaurant A  | png   | local   | mon-sun |   08:00   | 19:00      | none  |
| 45 | Restaurant B  | kdh   | western | mon-sun |   00:00   | 19:00      | none  |
| 46 | Restaurant C  | png   | western | mon-fri |   09:00   | 19:00      | none  |
| 46 | Restaurant C  | png   | western | sat-sun |   10:00   | 23:00      | wifi  |
| 46 | Restaurant C  | png   | western | sat-sun |   10:00   | 23:00      | coke  |
| 46 | Restaurant C  | png   | western | sat-sun |   10:00   | 23:00      | cofee |
+----+---------------+-------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+
```

As you can see restaurant with id `46` has multiple row due to multiple hours of operation (`day`, `open_time`, `close_time`) value or tag value.

This data quite cumbersome to work with, i cant assume each row belong to different restaurant

How can i make application code easier to process this data?

One way I can think of is merge restaurant into single row (Is this the right way? Is there any other way?)

Using `subquery` and `group_concat`, I end up with something like this:

```
+---------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
| restaurant_id | name                | state | cuisine | day                                 | open_time               | close_time                 | tag                     |
+---------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|            44 | Restaurant A        | png   | local   | mon-sun                             | 08:00                   | 19:00                      | none                    |
|            45 | Restaurant B        | kdh   | western | mon-sun                             | 00:00                   | 19:00                      | none                    |
|            46 | Restaurant C        | png   | western | mon-fri , sat-sun, sat-sun, sat-sun | 09:00,10:00,10:00,10:00 | 19:00, 23:00, 23:00, 23:00 | none, wifi, coke, cofee |
+---------------+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Generally this is what i have been doing for some time.
Application code just need to split by comma for any column that might have more than 1 value

**Question:**
1)Is this the right way to do it?
2)Is there a limit to column length, cause `group_concat` might produce very wide column

I would love to know how other programmer handle this kind of problem

**Edited**
Using php as an application code

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what your client application is written in and if it's being presented on the web. When you say "group concat" might produce a very wide column, I'm wondering if you're asking that because of a front issue or if you're worried that there's some kind of limit to how long it can me.

Comment: @JoeLove application code is php.Im worried if mysql impose how wide a column can be since group_concat might concat more than 20 row

Answer (score 1):

Multi value fields are always a pain to work with. Though the first method yields more columns it is also more concise and easy to query.

Short answer: If you value space choose option 2. If you value usability choose option 1.

Comment: I agree, I think the task of splitting (or merging, same thing) here shouldn't be done by SQL, as you probably would want to split/merge it into multiple-rows/single-rows. Which is hard to do and read when done in SQL. A program might do it "longer" but it will be more readable for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Group_concat might not be your best option, as there is a size limit (and it's not a hard limit, it's based on a few other settings). Quoting from the mysql 5.0 docs

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the
>   group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of
>   max_allowed_packet.

Just don't try a "one size fits all" query for everything you're doing. I'd not join to all the tables every time (if you don't have to), and only do that when needed. If you need to query this information most of the time, it may be easier to have a "post processing" function on your app side that converts this to an easier form-- like say, a multi dimensional array. Now, the fact that you have 2 1-many relationships going on, it compounds the problem. It may be easier to simply run nested queries, depending on how much data we're talking about-- IE, get all the restaurant data, then for each restaurant, get the hours, then get the tags. If this induces hundreds of queries, you can eliminate all of that by querying the restaurant table and then querying every row of the hours and tags tables, performing the "join" in your procedural code. The trick here is to do it in a way that can be used throughout your app without slowing things down or using too much memory. If we're talking about less than  few hundred restaurants and we don't have blob columns in there very large text columns, you should be good memory wise to load it all up and process in php.. otherwise, you may just have to process this as you go, which, as you're discovering is ugly.

The absolute best case is that you won't have to pool all of this data together most of the time.